# 16’ Wooden I-Beams sagging after additional weight added

Tags: framing, structural, cracks

We recently completed a renovation on the third floor of a 3-story structure built in 1999 that is supported by wooden I-beams. We added a tiled bathroom with a tiled shower, a hickory floor, which replaced carpet, and a single wall that includes a 36 inch solid core door. In the months following the renovation, we have noticed cracks in the ceiling drywall immediately below where the wall was framed in. The cracks are appearing at the tape seams, and most are hairline, with a few separated by 1/32 of an inch or so. They are appearing approximately halfway across the span of the I-beam. My question is: at what point do you think we should get nervous as the drywall tape cracks? How much disruption merits the consideration of an engineer coming to assess and/or running support beams down to the first floor? And Is this normal? We added weight to our second floor at one point, and never noticed these ceiling drywall cracks on the first floor.
Any insight would be super helpful and greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens depends on what loads the floor was designed to support. If the "3rd floor" was considered "attic" at build time, it may have been designed with lower floor loading than the second floor was - location of loads relative to supports also matters.

Comment: Do you know if the wall was put in tight(needing force to put in place) or loose(needing nails to hold it in place)?  A wall should not be that heavy, but if forced in might cause cracks.

Comment: Thanks for responding. @Ecnerwal it was intended as a living space from the beginning. Definitely not an attic.

Comment: @crip659, good question and I had the same thought. Need to ask the builder! Edit — it was framed in with a nailer, so I imagine it wasn’t too tight.

Comment: you need to measure the bow in the ceiling if any exists. If it does, that's a problem.

Comment: An experienced building inspector might be cheaper than an engineer yet able to tell you if there is a safety issue or not.